# NSManagedObjectのサブクラスの自作メソッドを呼ぶとunrecognized selector sent to instanceが発生する

Tags: xcode, objective-c, coredata

Xcode Version 8.1(8B62) DeploymentTarget iOS 8.4
Core Dataにデータを追加する処理を作っております。
Xcodeの機能でサブクラスを自動生成して自作メソッドを追加しました。

[image: Xcodeで作成したデータモデル]

```
// Media+CoreDataClass.h
@interface Media : NSManagedObject
    -(void)import:(NSArray *)received;
@end

@property (nullable, nonatomic, copy) NSString *id;
@property (nonatomic) int16_t diskNo;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;

// Media+CoreDataClass.m
-(void)import:(NSArray *)received {

    self.id = [received valueForKey:@"id"];
    self.diskNo = [(NSNumber *)[received valueForKey:@"diskNo"] intValue];
    self.title = [received valueForKey:@"title"];
}
```

以下は正常に終了するのですが、

```
appDelegate_ = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
context_ = appDelegate_.persistentContainer.viewContext;
Media *media = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Media"
                                             inManagedObjectContext:context_];
media.id = [json valueForKey:@"id"];
media.diskNo = [(NSNumber *)[json valueForKey:@"diskNo"] intValue];
media.title = [json valueForKey:@"title"];
[appDelegate_ saveContext];
```

以下のようにメソッド呼び出しをするとエラーとなります。

```
appDelegate_ = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
context_ = appDelegate_.persistentContainer.viewContext;
Media *media = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Media"
                                             inManagedObjectContext:context_];
[media import:json];
[appDelegate_ saveContext];
```

> -[Media import:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000002c2370
>      Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Media import:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000002c2370'

NSManagedObjectのサブクラスに自作メソッドの追加はできると様々なサイトに書かれていたのですが、やり方がまずい点があればご指摘お願い致します。

Comment: Core Dataのモデルに正しくクラス名を設定してやらないと、作成されるインスタンスはあなたの定義したサブクラスではなく、単なる`NSManagedObject`になります。データモデルインスペクタ上で[正しくClassは設定できています](https://developer.apple.com/jp/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/CreatingObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH5-SW3)か?

Comment: @OOPer Xcodeで作成したデータモデルのスクリーンショットを追加しました。クラスのところは同じになっているのを確認しました。

Comment: Mediaクラスの宣言がおかしく、定義が断片的過ぎるのではっきりとは分かりません。また、データモデルのCodegenをClass DefinitionにしているとXcodeが自動でMediaクラスを生成するのでなぜコンパイルが通るのかわかりません。

Comment: @masakih 解決しましたデータモデルのCodeineをClass Definitionにしていたのが原因でした。Manualに切り替えて実行すると自作メソッドを呼べました。ありがとうございました

Answer (score 1):

NSManagedObjectのサブクラスを生成して機能追加を行いたい場合
1. データモデルを作成する
2. Class - CodegenをManual/Noneにする
[image: Manual/None]
3. メニューよりEditor - Create NSManagedSubclassを選択
4. 生成されたサブクラスに機能追加を行う
5. コンパイル・リンク

サブクラスを生成せず(機能追加をせず)CoreDataを利用する場合
1. データモデルを作成する
2. Class - CodegenをClass Definitionにする
[image: Class Definition]
3. コンパイル・リンク

この時、メニューからCreate NSManagedSubclassでサブクラスを生成していた場合、リンク時に同名のクラスが既に存在する旨のエラーが発生する。（サブクラス一式をコンパイル・リンクの対象から外せばエラーは出なくなりますが、当然ながらこのまま実行すると例えば自分で追加したメソッドを呼び出した際は unrecognized selector sent to instance が発生する）